# construct a pairwise disjoint sequence $A_{n}$ in an Algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

For a $\sigma-$ algebra $\mathcal{A}$, we can construct a pairwise disjoint sequence $\{B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ such that $\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n = \sqcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} B_n$, where $\sqcup$ denotes a disjoint union.

It is not hard to construct that $B_1 = A_1$, $B_n = A_n - (\cup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j) \ \forall n \geq 2$.

> My question is how about $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra if I want to show that $\cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} A_n = \sqcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} B_n$? So how can I construct $B_j$'s?

I think it does not work if I let $B_1 = A_1$, $B_n = A_n - (\cup_{j=1}^{n-1}A_j)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your candidate $B_1=A_1$, $B_n = A_n \setminus \bigcup_{j < n} A_j$ works just fine. Clearly, the $B_n$ are disjoint. Since $B_n\subseteq A_n$ for all $n$, $$\bigsqcup B_n\subseteq \bigcup A_n.$$
Conversely, suppose $x\in\bigcup A_n$. Then $x\in B_{n_x}$, where
$$
n_x = \min\{n : x\in A_n\}.
$$
Therefore,
$$\bigcup A_n\subseteq \bigsqcup B_n.$$
So equality holds.

[Edited to address comment:] Note that we **do not assume** that $\bigsqcup B_n=\bigcup A_n$ belongs to the algebra $\mathcal{A}$. It need not! The result is just an identity of sets, not an identity of sets in $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: But in algebra, the countable union is not closed. How do you deal with that?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui -- see the comment I added to my answer.

Comment: The condition ... $\mathcal{A}$ is algebra and $A_{i}$'s are the subsets of $\mathcal{A}$. So I am confused about how to get the countable union of the $B_{j}$'s.

Comment: So you mean it does not matter what $\mathcal{A}$ are? Either algebra or $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Nitpick: The $A_i$ aren't subsets of $\mathcal{A}$, they are *elements* of $\mathcal{A}$. Each individual $B_j$ is constructed from only finitely many elements of the $A_i$, so each $B_j$ belongs to $\mathcal{A}$. I'm not sure what you mean by "getting the countable union". If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of subsets of some set $\Omega$, then taking a union of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ is just taking the union of certain subsets of $\Omega$. You don't need any extra structure to do that. Unless this union is finite, though, you can't make any conclusion about whether it belongs to $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: The only place where you use the fact that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra is to conclude that $B_n\in\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I am wrong because I always consider the $\cup B_{i}$ if or not in the algebra. But the point to let the $\cup B_{i}=\cup A_{i}.$ Thanks for your patience.